# How to align the center of a VStack to a point SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, vstack, hstack

I have 5 `VStacks` in an `HStack` that spans the width of the screen. The `VStack` contains `Text` Views that are all different widths because they display different text. What I want to do is align the **center** of each `VStack` so that they are evenly apart from each other and the edges of the screen. I know the width of the screen (I used `GeometryReader`) and I am pretty sure that to get the x value of each `VStack` I need to divide the width of the screen by 6, and that the center of each `VStack` should fall on the width of the screen divided by 6 and then multiplied by the number that represents its position in the `HStack` (so the first `VStack` at the top of the `HStack` would be 1). Since all of the `VStacks` have different widths I don't think I can use the `spacing` argument in the `HStack` to accomplish this. Thus I need a way to align the center of each `VStack` equally so that there is an even space between each of them and the edge of the screen.

Here is my code:

```
HStack() {
        VStack(spacing: 10){
            Text("123")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            Text("Value 1")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        }
        

        VStack(spacing: 10){
            Text("6534675")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            Text("Value 23")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        }
        
        VStack(spacing: 10){
            Text("6534")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            Text("Value 203")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        }
        
        VStack(spacing: 10){
            Text("1055")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            Text("Value 4589")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        }
        
        VStack(spacing: 10){
            Text("4")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            Text("Value 5")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        }
        
    }.frame(width: geo.size.width)
```

Comment: Not sure I understood what do you mean. The provided code even on iPhone 11 Pro Max fills screen tightly, making dynamic text a bit larger and layout looks bad, because of wrapped text. On SE it will be rather bad from default. So what's to goal? Sketch? Screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of the VStacks, you can work with .padding()

Syntax Example:

```
VStack(spacing: 10){
        Text("4")
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        Text("Value 5")
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
    }.padding(10)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the width of the VStacks, and the values in the text view are meant to be dynamic so I would constantly need to change the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Can use .position() to position the center of the view.

Detailed Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack-view-modifiers